# Horizontal content divs with right margin

Tags: css, xhtml

Here is my markup:

```
<div id="why-us">
    <span class="heading">Why Us?</span>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#why-us { float: left; }
#why-us span.heading { font-size: 13pt; color: #3A3A3A; display: block; }
#why-us div.section { float: left; width: 400px; margin-right: 50px; }
#why-us div.section p { font-size: 9pt; }
```

How can I make it only apply `margin-right: 50px;` to each `div.section` EXCEPT for the last one? Can this be done in pure CSS only? I don't ideally want to specify a ".last" class, nor use pseudo classes as the site needs to work in all browsers.

EDIT: Is there any nicer way of doing this? As I am now generating the code using PHP, which means I have to add extra code to make it check for the last DIV. I know that isn't too bad but still I would prefer a more elegant solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the CSS in the last div, as in:

```
<div id="why-us">
    <span class="heading">Why Us?</span>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section" style="margin-right: 0px;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's really ugly but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use child selectors as follows:

```
#why-us div.section:last-child{
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Br2DG/

Comment: last-child is not cross-browser compatible.

Comment: If you have jQuery included in the page, you can use that. That would be more reliable than the CSS only method.